# select query in view file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my simple php html code.

```
<select id="district" name="district">
    <option value="">Select district</option>
<?php 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM district";

    $result = mysqli_query($sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$district_id   = $row['district_id'] ;
$district_name = $row['district_name'];
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $district_id;?>"><?php echo $district_name;?></option>
<?php

}
?>      
</select>
```

But it's not working. database is autoloaded.What will be the problem.

Comment: You can call model function in view instead of calling query here.

Comment: then why you using codeigniter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are using direct query **not with CI db instance** so you will not getting db connection try in CI way

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM district";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row->district_id;?>"><?php echo $row->district_name;?></option>
<?php }
}
```

or

```
  $this->db->from('district');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if($query->num_rows > 0 ) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
      // do your stuff
    }
  }
```

**Better method to work with MVC framework**:- use model for db queries and return data on view via controller (do not use direct query on view)

Answer (score 2):

May be your get CI instance wirte you CI query directly

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('modelname');
$result = $CI->modelname->functionname();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must access db directly from, view try this:

```
$this->load->view('view_name',["db"=>$this->db,"other_data=>"data"]);
//$this->db //CI db instance
```

In view you can now do:

```
$db->query("select * from table")->result();
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this

```
<select id="district" name="district">
<option value="">Select district</option>
```

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
 $district_id   = $row['district_id'] ;
 $district_name = $row['district_name'];
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $district_id;?>"><?php echo $district_name;?></option>
<?php } ?>
```